# How to get structural union types in Scala?

Tags: scala, types, polymorphism, duck-typing

I'm not sure if "structural union types" is the right terminology, but I'm trying to get the following duck-typing behavior in Scala.

Suppose I have some container class `Container` with methods to get objects of type `A` and `B`:

```scala
class Container {
  def getA: A
  def getB: B
}
```

`A` and `B` both have a `commontIntField` attribute, but they also have some non-shared methods:

```scala
class A {
  val commonIntField: Int
  def getAStringField1: String
  def getAStringField2: String
}

class B {
  val commonIntField: Int
  def getBStringField: String
}
```

Now suppose I want to define the following three functions, which all look very similar to each other:

```scala
def f1(c: Container) = {
  val a = c.getA
  (0 to a.commonIntField) foreach { println(a.getAStringField1) }
}

def f2(c: Container) = {
  val a = c.getA
  (0 to a.commonIntField) foreach { println(a.getAStringField2) }
}

def f2(c: Container) = {
  val b = c.getB
  (0 to b.commonIntField) foreach { println(a.getBStringField) }
}
```

What I'm looking for is some way to DRY this up, e.g. something like this:

```scala
def f(getAOrB, getStringField)(c: Container) = {
  val aOrB = c.getAOrB
  (0 to aOrB.commonIntField) foreach { println(aOrB.getStringField) }
}
val f1 = f(_.getA, _.getAStringField1)
val f2 = f(_.getA, _.getAStringField2)
val f3 = f(_.getB, _.getBStringField)
```

**My question:** What type parameters can I use for `f` to get this to compile? (Assume here that I can't change the definitions of `Container`, `A`, or `B`, although I can of course define auxiliary types if I need to.)

Answer (score 1):

You should add a type parameter to `f` and constrain it.

So we firstly add parameter and refactor it correspondingly:

```
def f[T](tGetter: Container => T, getStringField: T => String)(c: Container) = {
  val t: T = tGetter(c)
  val intField =  getIntField(t)
  (0 to intField) foreach { println(stringGetter(t)) }
}
```

And there is a problem - how can we define the way how we fetch T from a Container?
Simpler way - just add `tGetter: Container => T` as the first parameter. This is additional param but it is simple, and it will help you in auto type deriving of the type parameter.

```
def f[T](tGetter: Container => T, getStringField: T => String)(c: Container) = {
  val t: T = tGetter(c)
  val intField: Int = ??? // getIntField(t)
  (0 to intField).foreach { _ => println(getStringField(t)) }
}
// val f1 = f(_.getA, _.getAStringField1) // the old one
val f1 = f[A](_.getA, _.getAStringField1)(_)
// val f2 = f(_.getA, _.getAStringField2)
val f2 = f[A](_.getA, _.getAStringField2)(_)
// val f3 = f(_.getB, _.getBStringField)
val f3 = f[B](_.getB, _.getBStringField)(_)
```

But there is a problem - how can we get the int field?
We have a few ways.

## 1. Structural typing

You simply express desired structural type like this `{ def commonIntField: Int }` and write upper type bound for T:

```
def f[T <: { def commonIntField: Int }](tGetter: Container => T, getStringField: T => String)(c: Container) = {
```

Or nicer variation with type alias:

```
type HaveIntField = { def commonIntField: Int }
def f[T <: HaveIntField](tGetter: Container => T, getStringField: T => String)(c: Container) = {
```

But structural typing is considered bad practice because it uses reflection and not very safe.

## 2. Type classes

You need to express that the T would have a way of getting the int field without a common supertype. You can add this functionality with type class pattern in scala. You can easily google guides on how to write type classes. I just will demonstrate the final result.
You would add a typeclass that says that your type has a way of getting the int field.

```
trait HaveIntField[X] {
  def getIntField(x: X): Int
}
```

Then you create instances of that type class for every class that you want to support in such functionality.

```
object HaveIntField {
  implicit val haveIntField_A_Instance: HaveIntField[A] = new HaveIntField[A] { 
    def getIntField(a: A): Int = a.commonIntField
  }
  implicit val haveIntField_A_Instance: HaveIntField[A] = new HaveIntField[A] { 
      def getIntField(a: A): Int = a.commonIntField
  }
}
```

And then finally you add the context bound on T.

```
def f[T: HaveIntField](tGetter: Container => T, getStringField: T => String)(c: Container) = {  
  val t: T = tGetter(c)
  val intField =  implicitly[HaveIntField[T]].getIntField(t)
  0 to intField) foreach { println(stringGetter(t)) }
}
```

This looks a little bit nasty and overwhelming in Scala 2, but it is a cool concept from FP/Haskell. And it would be very smooth in the upcoming Scala 3.